# How to move one edge's vertice without interrupting other mesh

Tags: modeling

How to move one edge's vertice without interrupting other mesh - Here on picture, how can I make one more white vertice and slide it to the right to make 2 squares instead of this weird looking n-gons.

EDIT: Here on picture you see I have selected one edge, and it has 2 vertices. That edge seperates mesh in 2 weird n-gons. Left one is triangle(marked as "1." at picture I uploaded), right one is some weird quadrangle. I want them to become 2 squares(something as close as marked in picture "2."), obviously by adding one vertice more but don't know exactly how.

Also, how can I make edge loop to continue through this n-gon, beacuse as you can see it stopped right top of orange vertice.

EDIT: I marked with red dashed line on the picture where I want to cut mesh, but can't do it with CTRL+R.
P.S.: sorry for the unclear information, but I am pretty new to Blender so I don't know proper vocabulary for those problems. Hope now it is little bit clearer.[image]

Comment: It's not clear, could you please try to reformulate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Connect Vertex Path & Dissolve Edge

You don't have to move any vertices: they all are right in place. What you want is to re-arrange the topology, aka changing the connections between them. You'll need this two tools:

Use **Connect Vertex Path** to create an edge between two vertex

> This tool connects vertices in the order they are selected, splitting
> the faces between them. When there are only two vertices selected, a
> cut will be made across unselected faces, a bit like the Knife tool;
> but this is limited to straight cuts across connected faces.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/vertex/connect_vertex_path.html

[image]

and then **Dissolve edges** to remove an existing edge:

> Removes edges sharing two faces (joining those faces).

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/delete.html

Comment: Hello, it helped a lot. I need to get used to it, but it is useful tool. Thanks!